# What is considered a valid C#/EDM identifier?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

Could someone please provide me with some more information about valid **C#/EDM identifiers**?

I was writing custom Annotations for EntityFramework Fluent API,
but they don't seem to register as expected...

I'm using [HasColumnAnnotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.propertymappingconfiguration.hascolumnannotation?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method and noticed that if I leave "Index" it'll register,
but it'll throw exception as well because then it's using IndexAnnotationSerializer which can't serialize custom Annotations.

Somewhere I've found that I can use "IndexExtensions" and that seems to be working but I would like to understand what I'm missing.

```
modelBuilder
            .Entity<QRLink>()
            .Property(p => p.Code)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(@"Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute(@"IX_Code")
            {
                IsUnique = true
            }));

modelBuilder
            .Entity<QRLink>()
            .Property(p => p.Code)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(@"CustomIndex", new CustomIndexAnnotation(new CustomIndexAttribute(@"IX_Code")
            {
                IsUnique = true,
                Where = @"Code IS NOT NULL"
            }));
```